# I want to make a navigation system where on click div changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After loading the page when I'm clicking the events, aboutus or contact us nav, the javascript is working i.e the div is being shown (initially in css I've kept the display:none; for div with id home,events,aboutus,contactus).But when I want to come to home from events, aboutus or contactus the div is not changing back (its not showing).Please help

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
<nav>
    <ul class="brand">
        <li><a href="#">title</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="#" id="home_nav">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="events_nav">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="about_us_nav">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="contact_us_nav">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="main-section">
    <div class="home" id="home"><h1>hello</h1></div>
    <div class="events" id="events"><h1>bonjour</h1></div>
    <div class="about_us" id="about_us"><h1>namaste</h1></div>
    <div class="contact_us" id="contact_us"><h1>ciao</h1></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#events_nav').click(function(){
    $('#events').show();
});
$('#home_nav').click(function(){
    $('#home').show();
});
$('#about_us_nav').click(function(){
    $('#about_us').show();
});

$('#contact_us_nav').click(function(){
    $('#contact_us').show();
});
```

The the css file I've kept the `display:none;` for div with ids - events,home,about_us,contact-us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a JSBin for you and changed up your code a bit to get the desired output. The main problem I think is that you want to manipulate CSS properties for visibility instead of display none. Visibility is not like Display. When you display none, you are essentially removing it from the DOM so you can't select it. When it's visibility is hidden, it is still selectable and modifiable.

Here's the link to the  working example: http://jsbin.com/foligufevo/edit?html,css,js,output

You might also want to start using $(#selector).on('event',fn) instead of binding to the click event. Here's the docs that describe why: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is wrong with your code is that you never hide the previously opened div. I am guessing your css customization is what is causing it to "never change", as the result is that two divs show after clicking two (and so on).

Comment: I think you are right. Can you please help me fix my code. I'll share my css file. The below code is just one of the div's

Comment: .main-section .events {
 background-image:url("../images/1 (3).jpg");
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-size:cover;
 width:99.8%;
 position:absolute;
 overflow-y:auto;
 overflow-x:auto;
    height:99.7%;
 z-index:-1;
}